# Querying MySQL event log for group members on a specific date

Tags: mysql

I'm using MySQL version 5.5.
I have an event log table with the following columns:

- id (INT, autoincrement)
- event_date (DATE)
- event_type (ENUM, 'ADDED' or 'REMOVED')
- group_id (INT, foreign key)
- user_id (INT, foreign key)

The table contains a log of events that happened when adding or removing users to groups. For example:

1, '2015-01-10', 'ADDED', 10, 200
  2, '2015-01-11', 'ADDED', 10, 300
  3, '2015-01-15', 'REMOVED', 10, 200

This means that the user with id "200" was member of the group with id "10" from the 10th of January to the 15th of January, both inclusive.

Similarly, the user with id "300" became a member of the group with id "10" the 11th of January and is still a member.

How can I construct a query that tells me, which users were on a specific date members of one or more of a specific set of groups?

I.e. the question could be: "On the 24th of October 2015, which users were members of either group 200 or 300?"

Comment: Is your database design fixed, or can you change it? This type of question would be a lot easier to answer with a table giving a relationship between users and groups, for example by having the date the user became a member, and the date the user left the group.

If you can't change the design, you might have to build a temporary table using the structure I've outlined to extract the information you are looking for.

Comment: The database design is fixed, unfortunately. I'm trying to query an already existing database created by a program for which I do not have the source code. I'm looking for a solution that can be expressed as a query, or perhaps as a MySQL procedure - I would rather not have to build up extra temporary tables using a seperate program.

Comment: I am making the assumption that the only way to know if someone is a member of a group on 2015-10-15 is to go though the complete log, from the beginning to the specified date, and see who became a member before 2015-10-15 and is still a member on 2015-10-15.

Is that assumption correct? 

How much data do you have and how far back does it go?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I have about 135,000 rows in the table spanning across approx. 3 years. However note that query only needs to look at the rows that have one of the specified group_ids - which means that the typical number of rows to go through is relatively small. The 135,000 rows are pretty evenly divided across approx. 3,000 groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on our discussion, I think that this query will give you what you want.

```
SELECT user_id FROM (
  SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM user_group 
    WHERE group_id IN (200, 300) AND event_date <= '2015-10-24'
    ORDER BY user_id, event_date desc, id desc, event_type desc) A
  GROUP BY user_id, group_id) B
WHERE event_type = 'ADDED'
GROUP BY user_id;
```

Comment: As far as I understand the query (please correct me, if I'm wrong) - it works by retrieving a list of log events sorted by user and date, and then relying on MySQLs implementation of GROUP BY to fetch only the first of these events for each user. I.e. you get a list of the most recent events for each user, and then take only those where the most recent event is added. However, I do not think that this query work for my scenario. Example: A user is added to groups 200 and 300, and then later removed from group 300. When queried if the user is in 200 or 300, the query will incorrectly say no?

Comment: I checked the query with a single group, so you might be right. You can change it by using `GROUP BY user_id, group_id`.

If you upload a subset of your data, I can use it to run some tests.

Comment: Hmm, yes - but then I would need to tack on an extra "GROUP BY user_id" at the end - right? (to get rid of duplicates for users that are members of more than one group)

Comment: I have checked the query against the data now, and my limited testing seems to indicate that it works. I have found an edge case in that the same user might be added to and removed from the same group on the same day, therefore I have changed the ORDER BY to also order by the id. I have changed the sorting order on event_type so that REMOVED comes before ADDED.

Comment: jpw: Why do you think that it would list the user as a member in that case? - I.e. what's to special about 2015-01-01 and 2015-02-01?
Regarding the non-determinism, that's what I wrote about in my first comment here - i.e. that we're relying on MySQL implementation of GROUP BY to fetch only the first of those events. That's okay for my purposes, as I'm only using MySQL.